# How to get file upload element's name (Node and formidable)

Tags: node.js, formidable

I am trying to build a form with multiple upload elements. I know that one element can be used to select multiple files for upload but I want to make sure I have separate upload locations.

I have been using formidable package and I am able to upload 2 different files from two different elements. However, I cannot control the upload location because I need to identify the element name before setting the location. I cannot read this via:

form.on('field', function (name, field) { ...}

...it does not provide the upload file element's details.

How can I identify my (to-be) uploaded file's originating element?

Answer (score 0):

Been trying, found it:

```
   form.on('fileBegin', function (name, file) {
   console.log(name);
   }
```

I was confused since this element detail does not appear in form.on('field', function (name, field) { ...}